# 500 Server Error on file_get_contents() in foreach

Tags: php, magento

I have a live Stock URL, which is a URL that you add SKU Numbers to on the end like this `34342323232|23232|2323232|232232`.

So i have wrote a script that pulls all the item numbers / Sku's from a Magento database, and runs 25 Sku's on the end of a URL then uses `file_get_contents` to get the data.

I've split the array in to chunks as the url can only handle about 25 at a time.

It runs in side a foreach loop, the Database bit works fine, the script seems to return a 500 error when it runs the `foreach` a few times.

I've tried a few things, turning up max_input_vars etc doesn't seem to help.

This will run every half hour or so and running 1000's of products, is there a better way to get data from the URL? a faster way that won't crash the server?

the foreach loop code is below.

```
$updatedStock = array();
    // Split Array in to chunks of 25
    foreach(array_chunk($productSkus_single, 25) as $sku_chunk) {

        // Add sku string to live url and get contents
        $LiveFeedStock = file_get_contents($stockFeedUrl . implode("|", $sku_chunk));

        // Turn file contents in to an array and Remove <br/> add to array
        $updatedStock[] = array_values(array_filter(explode("<br/>",$LiveFeedStock), 'strlen' ));
    }
```

if you need the rest of the code i can provide it, but this seems to be where it fails.

i'm aware of cURL, i've tried a few solutions but can't seem to get it to work well, but then again i don't really understand it.

i've already gone through threads on here and tried tons of solutions with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE

Error logs display

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
End of script output before headers: index.php
mod_fcgid: process 18805 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

Comment: It's possible that `set_time_limit()` failing. Try with `set_time_limit(0);` in your function and see if that helps.

Comment: Thank you, Where abouts do i put this? as i don't have set_time_limit in my code.

Comment: You can try at the beginning of your function. Also make sure that `file_get_content()` is enabled. Some servers are disabled it for some security reasons and if this is the case you should use `cURL`

Comment: Didn't make any difference i've placed it at the start of the foreach and tried at the start of the code. i get an internal server error, file_get_contents() is working as it works with just one request.

Comment: Can you check if `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in php.ini.

Comment: Yes thats turned on. file_get_contents works, i think it just times out.

Comment: With a 500, you should get a mention of the issue in the web server error logs - could you take a look and let us know what it says? (expect it's memory or timeout)

Comment: i get these 

mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds & End of script output before headers: index.php & mod_fcgid: process 17878 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL

Comment: in root of the site, you can see `index.php` file, take backup of that file and than uncommnet thisl ine : `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` and than check what error is coming, also check var/log folder errors....

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error by making the following changes

```
ProcessLifeTime 7200
IPCConnectTimeout 30
IPCCommTimeout 60
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 10000
FcgidConnectTimeout 600
FcgidIOTimeout 10000
```

Seems to run and work fine now.

Comment: where did you chang this?